# Jquery Chosen - Chosen appears before clicking the drop-down list

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have just started using JQuery Chosen in my website. After calling .chosen() in $(document).ready for 2  drop-down lists, I receive this output:

https://www.mediafire.com/?3ld9sw734582usf

I use ajax to push data to the 2 drop-down lists. Here is how I do it:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    cache: false,
    url: "/ServiceLocation/ShowServices",
    beforeSend: function() {
        $('#ddlSer').chosen();
    },
    success: function (data) {
        $('#ddlSer').empty();

        $.each(data, function(idx, elem) {
            var serv = service.replace("[SERVICE]", elem.ServiceName);
            serv = serv.replace("[SERVICEID]", elem.ServiceId);

            $('#ddlSer').append(serv);
        });

        $('#ddlSer').trigger('liszt:updated');
    },
    error: function () {
        alert('Could not get the list of services.');

        return false;
    }
});

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    cache: false,
    url: "/ServiceLocation/ShowLocations",
    beforeSend: function () {
        $('#ddlLoc').chosen();
    },
    success: function (data) {
        $('#ddlLoc').empty();

        $.each(data, function(idx, elem) {
            var loc = locat.replace("[LOCNAME]", elem.LocationName);
            loc = loc.replace("[LOCID]", elem.LocationId);

            $('#ddlLoc').append(loc);
        });

        $('#ddlLoc').trigger('liszt:updated');
    },
    error: function () {
        alert('Could not get the list of locations.');

        return false;
    }
});
```

And here are the 2 variables I use to append data to drop-down lists:

```
var service = "<option value='[SERVICEID]'>[SERVICE]</option>";
var locat = "<option value='[LOCID]'>[LOCNAME]</option>";
```

Is there anything I did that made the 2 Chosen drop-down lists look ugly like that? 
I appreciate your assistance. Thanks in advance!

P/S: I tried using Chosen after pushing data to drop-down lists. It did not work, neither.

EDIT:

I used chosen.css and my custom one. This is the part in my custom css that is related to my Chosen drop-down list:

```
#ddlLoc_chzn .chzn-single {
height: 35px;
line-height: 35px;
width: 200px !important;
}

#ddlLoc_chzn b {
margin-top: 5px;
}

#ddlLoc_chzn .chzn-drop {
width: 200px !important;
}

#ddlLoc_chzn .chzn-search input {
width: 190px !important;
padding-right: 0px;
padding-left: 4px;
}
```

Comment: it seems like a css issue. dynamically adding the data will not break the chosen in any way. make sure you have the right css files added.

Comment: @AntoJSubash Thank you for your assistance! I use the correct chosen.css file. The members in my dev team used it and it was normal. I wonder if it is because of my custom css file...